# Send Combination-keystrokes using sendKeyEvent in a Mozilla/Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am building a Mozilla Extension and I need to send the window keystrokes using the `sendKeyEvent` function. I have it working when I send a single keystroke to the window but it is not working when I try to send a multi-keystroke pattern (ie. SHIFT+3 to send the # character). Does anyone have any idea how to send multiple keys to the window? I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var utils = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
utils.sendKeyEvent("keydown", 51, 51, 4);
utils.sendKeyEvent("keypress", 51, 51, 4);
utils.sendKeyEvent("keyup", 51, 51, 4);
```

I researched the web but I cannot find any examples of multi-key combinations.

UPDATE:: OK so the reason why I asked this question is because I am building a custom FF extension that will interact with a website. On the website they have some shortcut keys, and in the extension I would like to trigger a couple short-cut key events. One such shortcut is the SHIFT+3 (# pound sign). So on the site I believe they have something like the following:

```
function key_event(evt)
{
     if(evt.keyCode == 16) {
         if(evt.keyCode == 51){ 
           FIRE EVENT
         }
     }
}
```

Now does anyone know how I can trigger this event in javascript since the sendKeyEvent doesn't seem to trigger it? My initial thought is to create a while loop which presses the SHIFT key and setup an interval to press the 3 key. At some point they would have to be triggered at the same time? Not sure if this would be the best way. Any guidance/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For the Octothorpe ("# character"), did you try sending its ASCII code?  That is, use **35** instead of 51.?

Comment: Hey Brock, thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that didn't work. I've updated my question with some more specifics of what I think is 1) the site is listening for and 2) My idea of what might need to happen to trigger the key event

Comment: Hey @Brock, you are the man! Your solution actually worked, sorry about my comment above. If you want to add it as an answer I will mark it as resolved and give you credit. Thanks again!

Comment: Done.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Octothorpe ("# character"), try sending its ASCII code. That is, use 35 instead of 51.

Something like:

```
utils.sendKeyEvent("keypress", 35, 35, 4);
```